# Get input type file value inside widget

Tags: php, html, wordpress, file

I'am creating a widget, with the following functionality: Users can add images to their and they could be displayed on the front-end. I have admin.php file, when i create the input type file form.
In my.widget.php is the main widget file. In this function:

```
    public function widget( $args, $instance ) {

            if ( ! isset ( $args['widget_id'] ) )
                $args['widget_id'] = $this->id;

            extract( $args, EXTR_SKIP );

            $widget_string = $before_widget;

            $title = isset( $instance[ 'my-file' ] ) ? $instance[ 'my-file' ] : '';

 }
```

I've tried to save the input type file "my-file", but after clicking the "Save" button, it is not saved. Also i've tried with `$_FILES[ 'my-file' ]`, but still doesn't save.
Note: if i change the input type to "text", it's saving, but with file - not.
The question is: How could i save the input type file inside the widget ?

Answer (score 0):

Below is the full code of create widget and save fields in database.

Add code in function.php file

```
require get_template_directory().'/classes/widget.php';
$widgets  = new wpb_widget();
```

Add below code in widget.php file that we have include in above code.

// Creating the widget

```
class wpb_widget extends WP_Widget {

function __construct() {
parent::__construct(
// Base ID of your widget
'wpb_widget', 

// Widget name will appear in UI
__('Services Widget', 'wpb_widget_domain'), 

// Widget description
array( 'description' => __( 'Sample widget based on Services Widget', 'wpb_widget_domain' ), ) 
);
}
```

// Creating widget front-end

// This is where the action happens

```
public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
global $wpdb;        
$title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title'] );
$numberofpost = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['numberofpost'] );
// before and after widget arguments are defined by themes
echo $args['before_widget'];
if ( ! empty( $title ) )
echo '<div class="glossymenu"><div class="acor">';    

echo $args['before_title'];
echo '<h2 class="menuitem submenuheader"><span class="glossyspan">'.$title.'</span></h2>';; 
echo '<div style="text-align:right">
                <a href="" class="prevprog"><img src="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/images/inner_prev.png" alt="inner_prev"></a>
                <a href="" class="nextprog"><img src="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/images/inner_next.png" alt="inner_next"></a>
            </div>';


echo $args['after_title'];

$query = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'services','posts_per_page'=>$numberofpost,'orderby'=> 'ID','order' => 'DESC'));
$totalrecord = $query->post_count;
echo '<div id="programs">';
$mm = 0;
while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
$thumb_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), array(127, 123) );
          if($mm == 0)
          {  
            echo '<div class="submenu"><ul>';
          }  
          $expert = strip_tags(get_the_excerpt());

            if (strlen($expert) > 56) {

                // truncate string
                $stringCut = substr($expert, 0, 56);

                // make sure it ends in a word so assassinate doesn't become ass...
                $expert = substr($stringCut, 0, strrpos($stringCut, ' ')); 
            }

          echo '<li>
              <img width="58" src="'.$thumb_image_url[0].'" alt="'.$totalrecord.'" />
              <span class="bText">'.get_the_title().'</span>
              <span class="sText">'.$expert.'</span></li>';
          $mm++;
          if($mm == 4 or ($totalrecord == $mm))
          {    
            echo '</ul></div>';
            $mm = 0;
          }  

endwhile; wp_reset_query();          
echo '</div>';
echo '</div></div>';
echo $args['after_widget'];
}
```

// Widget Backend

```
public function form( $instance ) {
if ( isset( $instance[ 'title' ] ) ) {
$title = $instance[ 'title' ];
}
else {
$title = __( 'Services', 'wpb_widget_domain' );
}
if ( isset( $instance[ 'numberofpost' ] ) ) {
$numberofpost = $instance[ 'numberofpost' ];
}
else {
$numberofpost = __( '5', 'wpb_widget_domain' );
}
// Widget admin form
?>
<p>
<label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Title:' ); ?></label> 
<input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $title ); ?>" />
</p>
<p>
<label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'numberofpost' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Number of posts to show:' ); ?></label> 
<input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'numberofpost' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'numberofpost' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $numberofpost ); ?>" />
</p>
<?php 
}

// Updating widget replacing old instances with new
public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
$instance = array();
$instance['title'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['title'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['title'] ) : '';
$instance['numberofpost'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['numberofpost'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['numberofpost'] ) : '';
return $instance;
}
}
```

// Class wpb_widget ends here